# What are the temporary 'object' files (with alphanumeric file extensions) that are created during C compilation?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, object-files

When I compile my C program I get certain files that are created temporarily for each object file.  These temporary files are entitled `utilities.o-fb62414b` etc (i.e. `something.o-suffix` where 'something' is my object file and the suffix is alpha numeric characters).  I can't find a description of these temporary files anywhere.  They are not there when I `ls` after compilation is complete and they are not simply `*.o` files.  They only briefly pop-up in the window if I watch while compilation occurs (or do an `ls` from another terminal while compilation is occurring).

The compilation options I'm using are `-Wall -fmessage-length=0 -pg -O3`. 
 I'm also using the `gsl` library.  I'm using `gcc` on a Macbook Pro (10.12.6) for compilation and linking.

Any help on what these temporary files are?

Comment: I just note that these are not the same files as are output when using `-save-temps=obj` (which creates the `.bc`, `.i`, `.s` files).

Comment: `c object file` is an easy search for more information. The suggested duplicate should answer your question. Unless you'd like to know specifically why they show up *temporarily*, and are cleared after compilation. That is, is your question about the object files, or about them being temporary?

Comment: Thanks all.  I should have been clearer - my question is about those files being temporary.  Are they simply copies of the object files?  Why do they need to be temporary?

Comment: C object files end in `*.o` the files I'm talking about end in `.o-fb62414b` (or some other alpha numeric suffix).  So I'm interested in these other files.

Comment: Adding `-v` to the command line may help understand.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they actually are proper object files, and the `-<random>` part appended to the name is just that: to give them a random filename that doesn't clash with existing file names. That the extension isn't properly `.o` anymore doesn't matter: the file type and contents is the same. At the end of the compilation, they get merged into the finally executable or library.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile and link a program like so:

```
gcc -o hellow hello_world.c
```

you are using a shorthand that GCC helpfully expands into the necessary compile
step and link step, as if you had done:

```
gcc -c -o hello_world.o hello_world.c   # compile
gcc -o hellow hello_world.o     # link
rm hello_world.o      # Delete the intermediate object file
```

But since the shorthand does not specify any name for the intermediate object
file in the compile step (like `-o hello_world.o`), GCC generates a temporary
filename to which the object file is written. That's what you are seeing.

On Mac OS, `gcc` by default is an alias for `clang`. Clang
behaves like the real GCC in this respect (although the temporary filenames
it generates conform to a different template from real GCC's). The fact
that they don't have a `.o` extension on your MacBook doesn't matter: an object
file is an object file regardless of extension, and the linker will recognize
it as such.